# Work with SVG through an object, does not want to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I draw prompts on an interactive map, in js a beginner, did svg at first inside the file, but later decided to output svg via object, and there are already problems, I got the object itself, and I don’t quite understand how to transfer it to the code further

```html
<object data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="svgmap" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

<div class="map-tooltip"></div>
```

```js
var svgobject = document.getElementById('svgmap');
var svgdom = svgobject.contentDocument;

var tooltip = document.querySelector('.map-tooltip');
var contents = {};

contents['dom-48-a'] = '<img src="img/1.jpg"><h1>тест</h1><p>тест</p>';
contents['dom-37-9'] = '<img src="img/1.jpg"><h1>тест 2</h1><p>тест 2</p>';




[].forEach.call(svgdom.querySelectorAll('.HI-map'), function(item) {

  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open(this.getAttribute('data-link'));
  });


  item.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    tooltip.innerHTML = contents[item.getAttribute('data-tooltip')];
    tooltip.style.display = 'block';
  });

  item.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {



  tooltip.style.top =
      (e.pageY + tooltip.clientHeight + 10 < svgdom.body.clientHeight)
          ? (e.pageY + 10 + "px")
          : (svgdom.body.clientHeight + 5 - tooltip.clientHeight + "px");

  tooltip.style.left =
      (e.pageX + tooltip.clientWidth + 10 < svgdom.body.clientWidth)
          ? (e.pageX + 10 + "px")
          : (svgdom.body.clientWidth + 5 - tooltip.clientWidth + "px");



  });


  item.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by a) does not want to work and b) transfer it to the code further. What happens? What do you expect to happen instead? Which line fails?

Comment: I inserted svg code into the page with the script, and tooltips worked, but when I inserted the svg via object, the code stopped working, and I don’t quite understand how to redo it

Comment: You don't seem to have waited for the object to load. Is svgobject.contentDocument valid or is it null?

Comment: Yes, I checked the object loads

Comment: checked how? What I mean is you're not waiting for the onload event of the object tag to fire.

Comment: window.addEventListener("load", function() { ....  });

thanks for the responsiveness, I realized what the error was, the chrome browser blocked receiving svg, I uploaded the files to the server and it worked